# xmonad-contrib Prompt: Execute terminal prompt in a particular workspace?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I recently decided to build XMonad from source via Stack to make a custom configuration. Let me preface by saying I do not have a ton of experience with Haskell.
My OS is Linux - Arch.

#### Setup

I am attempting to make use of the `XMonad.Prompt` package from xmonad-contrib in order to launch some applications.
(https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Prompt.html)

Currently, one prompt I am using is `XMonad.Prompt.Man`, which launches the `man` program with a provided argument in the default terminal (the terminal I default to is Alacritty).
(docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Prompt-Man.html)
(src: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-Prompt-Man.html)

What I do not understand is how to use this prompt to launch the terminal to workspace 2, where I would like all my manpages to open.

#### The way the prompt works as of right now:

I have a keybinding set up in `xmonad.hs`, something like the following:

```
...
, ("M-C-m", manPrompt myPromptConfig)
...
```

This works how the documentation says it should, but the manpages always open in the current workspace, not in workspace 2 where I want them to.

#### What I have tried

Because `man` opens in an existing terminal and does not provide options for setting the window name, I was initially not able to use `ManageHook` to detect the window name and shift it over to the correct workspace, like I do for applications like Mozilla Firefox: (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-ManageHook.html)

```
myManageHook = composeAll
    [
    ...
    , title =? "Mozilla Firefox" -> (doShift !! myWorkspaces 1)
    ...
    ]
```

I have tried setting the window name to something hard-coded using Alacritty's `--title` option, but that only shifts the terminal after it has been spawned and `man` has already been invoked on the current layout, resulting in incorrect text alignment when the terminal gets shifted to a different workspace with a different layout.

I thought a proper solution might require modifying the source code of `XMonad.Prompt.Man`.

Looking at the source code for `XMonad.Prompt.Man`, I saw that this line might be useful to change (line 60-63): (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-Prompt-Man.html)

```
manPrompt :: XPConfig -> X()
manPrompt c = do         -- NOTE FROM ME: getMans and manCompl are functions defined elsewhere in the file that are not relevant here
    mans <- io getMans
    mkXPrompt Man c (manCompl c mans) $ runInTerm "" . (++) "man "
```

Looking at the source code for `runInTerm` (from `XMonad.Util.Run`), it looks to me like it takes 2 string args: the first being a list of options, `""` in the case of `manPrompt` (i.e. blank by default), and the second being the command to run, `"man "` in the case of `manPrompt`. These both get run in the default terminal (Alacritty for me).
(docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Util-Run.html)
(src: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/src/XMonad.Util.Run.html#runInTerm)

Is there something I can do to modify `manPrompt` or `runInTerm` so that I can specify which workspace the terminal spawned by `manPrompt` spawns in? Or is there any other way anyone knows of achieving my desired behavior that I do not know about?

#### EDIT #1

At the suggestion of a recent answer, I am attempting to patch the code for `manPrompt` to run `spawnOn` from `XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn`,  rather than `runInTerm`.
(https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html)

Here is what I have right now:

```
manPrompt :: XPConfig -> WorkspaceId -> String -> X ()
manPrompt promptConfig workspaceId terminalArgs = do
    mans <- io getMans
    mkXPrompt (showXPrompt "man ") promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans) $ spawnOn (workspaceId) $ (myTerminal) ++ " " ++ (terminalArgs) ++ " -e man "
```

However, this will not compile, resulting in the error:

```
 xmonad.hs:248:78: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `String -> X ()'
                  with actual type `X ()'
    * In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `spawnOn (workspaceId)
           $ (myTerminal) ++ " " ++ (terminalArgs) ++ " -e man "'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        mkXPrompt
          (showXPrompt "man ") promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans)
          $ spawnOn (workspaceId)
              $ (myTerminal) ++ " " ++ (terminalArgs) ++ " -e man "
      In the expression:
        do mans <- io getMans
           mkXPrompt
             (showXPrompt "man ") promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans)
             $ spawnOn (workspaceId)
                 $ (myTerminal) ++ " " ++ (terminalArgs) ++ " -e man "
    |
248 |   mkXPrompt (showXPrompt "man ") promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans) $ spawnOn (workspaceId) $ (myTerminal) ++ " " ++ (terminalArgs) ++ " -e man "
    |                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume this issue is with my failure to grasp Haskell datatypes properly, but I do not understand...if the proper way to invoke `spawnOn` is `spawnOn <workspaceId> <command>`, how can I pass a `String` bash command to the function as `<command>`, like above?

#### EDIT #2 -- SOLUTION #1

My current solution is to use a custom patch of `XMonad.Prompt.Man`, with a `manPrompt` that looks like the following:

```
manPrompt :: XPConfig -> WorkspaceId -> String -> X ()
manPrompt promptConfig workspaceId terminalArgs = do
    mans <- io getMans
    mkXPrompt Man promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans) $
    \input -> spawnOn workspaceId $ myTerminal ++ " " ++ terminalArgs ++ " -e man " ++ input
```

This compiles and works, I guess, but it seems that the use of `spawnOn` still results in the same text alignment issues as with `doShift` when moving the terminal windows between workspaces with different layouts. (I mentioned these in the original post under **What I have tried**.)

To better explain what I mean by "text alignment issues," I included a screenshot here: https://ibb.co/vxjcKZh
(This screenshot is the result of summoning the prompt on a workspace with a squished layout. I then switched my focus over to the workspace that the manpages got spawned on, which should be full-screen, but you can see, the text does not fill the entire terminal window; this is because the `man` command ran when the window size was squished.)

Is there a way I can refresh the text in terminal window somehow after it spawns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tweaked version of `runInTerm` would indeed be a good fit here. `runInTerm` [is defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/src/XMonad.Util.Run.html#runInTerm):

```
unsafeRunInTerm, runInTerm :: String -> String -> X ()
unsafeRunInTerm options command = asks (terminal . config) >>= \t ->
    unsafeSpawn $ t ++ " " ++ options ++ " -e " ++ command
runInTerm = unsafeRunInTerm
```

`unsafeSpawn`, in turn, is an alias for [`spawn` from `XMonad.Core`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:spawn). There is a [`spawnOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html#v:spawnOn) variation on it in `XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn` which takes a `WorkspaceId` in addition to the command to be ran. It seems like using `spawnOn` to define a custom `runInTerm` would be enough to get what you want.

---

On the attempt in your edit, the final argument to [`mkXPrompt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Prompt.html#v:mkXPrompt) should be a `String -> X ()` function, rather than a `X ()` action. The `String` argument stands for the completion chosen by the user in the prompt, which, in your case, would be the argument to `man`. In the original implementation of `manPrompt`, the `String -> X ()` function is:

```
runInTerm "" . (++) "man "
```

Or, rephrasing it in an arguably clearer style:

```
\completion -> runInTerm "" ("man " ++ completion)
```

Your `manPrompt` can be adjusted accordingly:

```
manPromptOn :: XPConfig -> WorkspaceId -> String -> X ()
manPromptOn promptConfig workspaceId terminalArgs = do
    mans <- io getMans
    mkXPrompt Man promptConfig (manCompl promptConfig mans) $
        \completion -> spawnOn workspaceId $
            myTerminal ++ " " ++ terminalArgs ++ " -e man " ++ completion
```

(Note that I have additionally changed the first argument to `mkXPrompt`, as passing a string won't work. I'm also assuming this function is being added to something like a modified copy of [the `XMonad.Prompt.Man` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.0/docs/XMonad-Prompt-Man.html), as neither the `Man` constructor nor the `getMans` function are exported by the original version of the module.)

Comment: Thanks; this is very helpful! Unfortunately, I am running into a compilation error now when trying to implement this. I appended the details of it in an edit made to the original question. Hopefully, it is an easy fix.

Comment: @OhFiveight You are on the right track. I have edited the answer to cover the type error; let me know if it helps.

Comment: Big help! I added a second edit to my original question with some more details; in short, it mostly works now thanks to you.

Comment: @OhFiveight Great! On the text wrapping issue, for now the only thing I can add is that what happens doesn't depend on XMonad alone. For instance, if I create a narrow Alacritty window in a workspace with the `Tall` layout, run e.g. `rsync --help` in it and then shift the window to a `Full` workspace, Alacritty will rewrap the printed help text as you'd have wanted; however, as you note, that won't happen if I run `man rsync` instead of `rsync --help`.